# ggplot plotting empty months

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm still fairly new to R and have struggled to find a solution.

I have a list that is comprised of 12 dataframes corresponding to each month. (Data$January, Data$February etc).

Each dataframe contains timeseries data for the the month over a range of years. I wanted to visualize this data, but when I try ggplot using

```
ggplot(Data$January, aes(x = `Date`, y = `WaterLevel`)) +  
   geom_point()
```

The January data shows up, however the plot shows the span of years but includes empty months february - December. Is there anyway to have the plot only show the January month?

The structure of the data is:

'data.frame':   15412 obs. of  13 variables:

$ Date                                          : Date, format: "2006-01-01" "2006-01-02" "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" ...

$ Station                                  : chr  "NBS01" "NBS01" "NBS01" "NBS01" ...

$ Station.Id                                    : num  324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 ...

$ Water_level: num  201 203 203 203 203 206 206 208 208 208 ...

$ Equivalent           : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

$ site_id                                       : num  324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 ...

$ POSIXct                                       : POSIXct, format: "2006-01-01" "2006-01-02" "2006-01-03" "2006-01-04" ...

$ wtr_lvlp                                        : num  186 190 191 191 191 ...

$ equiv_p                                       : num  0.683 0.711 0.699 0.691 0.681 ...

$ wtrlvl_Diff                                      : num  14.8 12.9 12.3 11.8 11.6 ...

$ equiv_Diff                                 : num  0.683 0.711 0.699 0.691 0.681 ...

$ wtrlvl_RMSE                                      : num  84.1 84.1 84.1 84.1 84.1 ...

$ equiv_RMSE                                     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

Edit 3: dp(head(data$January))

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13149, 13150, 13151, 13152, 
13153, 13154), class = "Date"), Station = c("NBS01", 
"NBS01", "NBS01", "NBS01", "NBS01", "NBS01"
), Station.Id = c(324, 324, 324, 324, 324, 324), Water_level = c(201, 
203, 203, 203, 203, 206), Equivalent = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), site_id = c(324, 
324, 324, 324, 324, 324), POSIXct = structure(c(1136073600, 1136160000, 
1136246400, 1136332800, 1136419200, 1136505600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), wtr_lvlp = c(186.2000028, 190.1000028, 
190.7000028, 191.2000028, 191.4000029, 191.6000029), equiv_p = c(0.682899983, 
0.711299982, 0.699199982, 0.690699983, 0.681199983, 0.672699983
), wtrlvl_Diff = c(14.79999723, 12.89999717, 12.29999716, 11.79999715, 
11.59999715, 14.39999714), equiv_Diff = c(0.682899983, 0.711299982, 
0.699199982, 0.690699983, 0.681199983, 0.672699983), wtrlvl_RMSE = c(84.1300149026027, 
84.1300149026027, 84.1300149026027, 84.1300149026027, 84.1300149026027, 
84.1300149026027), equiv_RMSE = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = 1097:1102, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The answer likely depends greatly on the structure and contents of `Data`.  Can you provide us with `Data$January`?  The easiest way to do this is to copy and paste the output of `dput(Data$January)` into the question.

Comment: Sure, but its quite long.Please give me a second to edit the post.

Comment: `dput(head(Data$January))` is also fine if it is very long otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, OP.  Based on what you shared, this plots just fine: `ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) + geom_point()`.  Note that you had single quotes around the column names and "Water_level" had a misspelling vs. your dataset.  Is that the issue here?

Comment: No, I apologize. I typed in my code up top incorrectly (WaterLevel as opposed to Water_level), but it is correct in R. The plot that appears shows the data I want, yes, but there are blank spaces in between the years which I am assuming is because the plot is taking into account feb-dec. Thus the data for january looks compressed and vertical in interations, where I would want them spread out. I also tried facet_grid() but I'm still running into the same problem where the entire year is being shown for the data it seems like.

Comment: I just re-created your setup by making two dataframes with random data one spanning Jan and one spanning days in Feb, then joined them.  Plotting with the same code shows me a plot that looks just fine (no bleeding of one date pattern into another).  Is the output of the dataset you shared the entire one, or just the top few obs?  I think you must have some observations that are Feb-Dec in that `Data$January` data.frame.  If it is a large dataset, it might be advisable to share a **sample** of the dataset, so we can see it all.  Ex: `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 20),])` where df=your data frame.

Comment: There isn't any bleeding, its just that the intervals are wrong? I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting what you are seeing or if I am explaining it incorrectly, but on the X axis - 2006, 2007, 2008 , 2009 etc show up. each year is marked. However, rather than the data in January 2006 taking up the entire grid block for 2006 and then continuing to January 2007, there are these large gaps between each January set of data before starting the next. I want to get rid of that excess gap between each of the sets of data to visualize each point more discretely.

Comment: oooohhhhhhhh..... now I get it.  What you shared was only the first few days of the dataset, which shows data for January of *each* of those years.  Yes, that was not too clear from the information.  Do you want to show an aggregate of all January points for all years on the plot?  Are you differentiating Jan 2006 from Jan 2007, for example?

Comment: Yes sorry for not explaining it more clearly, I've been trying to figure this out all day along with trying apply a function over the each of the dataframes and neither has been going well haha. Yeah, ideally, I would use facet_grid() to have separate plots of each of those years for January, however using that or just plotting it all onto one plot, the points come off really compressed versus the empty space on the plots. If using facet, I guess maybe setting maximum limits would help?  But on the regular single plot, the spacing between each January set makes seeing individual points diffic

Comment: Regarding the facet_grid solution, you need to set the parameter `scales` to `'free_x'` or `'free'` (see answers below). This way each facet will have its own range in the xaxis. If you don't do this, all facets will have the same range in the xaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you only gave data for the year 2006, so we cannot observe your issue. I expanded your data frame with dummy data to include values in january 2007. I am also only keeping the two columns that you are using in your plot

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(13149, 13150, 13151, 13152, 13153, 13154,13514,13515,13516,13517,13518,13519), class = "Date"), 
                     Water_level = c(201, 203, 203, 203, 203, 206, 211,213,213,213,213,216)), row.names = 1:12, class = "data.frame")
```

Because your `Date` column is in date format, ggplot interprets the data in this column as a date and will plot the points taking into account the actual time difference between them. That is if you have a point at date "2006-01-01" and another point at date "2007-01-01", in the plot they will be 365 days apart (as they should) and the dates between will appear in the xlabel.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

From you question it seems that you would like the data from the january months in different years to be visually concatenated, so that "2007-01-01" follows directly after "2006-01-31".

#### Quick and dirty solution

One quick way to accomplish this is to transform the date column into a factor (a categorical variable). When you do this, your first date will be the first level in your categorical variable, the second date your second level, and so on. Since you have only january dates, this will result in "2007-01-01" following directly after "2006-01-31".

```
# transform Date column to categorical variable
df$Date <- as.factor(df$Date) 

# plot again
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

This solution is quick but has some pitfalls. First, it could be confusing to someone to see these different dates concatenated. Also, if your dataset skips some days (e.g. goes from "2006-01-05" to "2006-01-15") the points will appear consecutively in your plot (since they will be consecutive "categories"). And also, you would probably need to work with the labels in the xaxis since they would end up over each other.

#### Better solution (in my opinion)

A better solution would be to create another column with the year of the data (using **the original data frame with dates**) and then plot each year in different facets.

```
# this package helps to do manipulations with dates
library(lubridate)

#create column with year
df$year <- year(df$Date)

#create plots separating each year in a different facet (scales = "free_x" is important!)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(vars(year), scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can reproduce the relevant data structure like this:

```r
set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date("2006-01-01") + lubridate::days(0:3651),
                 Water_level = cumsum(runif(3652, -0.2, 0.2)) + 200)

Data <- split(df, month.name[lubridate::month(df$Date)])
```

Now we have 12 data frames in a list. Each data frame is named after a month but spans several years.

So your plot presumably looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data$January, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) +  
  geom_point()
```

[image]

But we can fix it by adding month and year columns to each frame, then faceting:

```r
library(lubridate)

Data <- lapply(Data, function(x) { x$month <- month.name[month(x$Date)]; x})
Data <- lapply(Data, function(x) { x$year  <- year(x$Date); x})

ggplot(Data$January, aes(x = Date, y = Water_level)) +  
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(year), scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The master of recreating data structures has returned! `cumsum(runif...))` amazing!